# Solving nonlinear differential first order equations using Python

Tags: python, math, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I would like to solve a nonlinear first order differential equation using Python.

For instance,

df/dt = f**4

I wrote the following program, but I have an issue with matplotlib, so I don't know if the method I used with scipy is correct.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
derivate=lambda f,t: f**4
f0=10
t=np.linspace(0,2,100)
f_numeric=scipy.integrate.odeint(derivate,f0,t)
print(f_numeric)
plt.plot(t,f_numeric)
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint'
```

Comment: try `t=np.linspace(0,0.00033,1000)`

Comment: That's strange because the code above works fine for me when I change `scipy.integrate.odeint` to `odeint` (since you actually didn't import the scipy namespace, the odeint function should be called just by its name)

Comment: @HYRY : I tried `t=np.linspace(0,0.00033,1000)` and it works for this t, how can I make it work for `t=np.linspace(0,2,100)` ?

@Azrathud : It works with your advice... but not all the time. Actually, if you try my code 10 times, it won't work 10 times : there will be the `AttributeError`. Do you have another advice to make it work ?

Comment: @Jack,  please check the symbol solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=df%2Fdt%20%3D%20f**4

Comment: @HYRY : I used your link with `df/dt = f^4, f(0)=10`, and WolframAlpha gives `f(x) = 10 / (1 - 3000x)^(1 / 3)` as the solution.
Then I plotted the solution on Geogebra and it isn't the same as the result drawn after I run the code.

Comment: Solutions will be timestep-dependent, particularly as timesteps approach the stability limit and particularly for nonlinear problems. So different solutions are to be expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you might be better of using [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html), which allows you to obtain the closed form solutions:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy
from sympy.solvers.ode import dsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython


t = sy.symbols("t", real=True)
f = sy.symbols("f", function=True)


eq1 = sy.Eq(f(t).diff(t), f(t)**4)  # the equation 
sls = dsolve(eq1)  # solvde ODE

# print solutions:
print("For ode")
display(eq1)
print("the solutions are:")
for s in sls:
    display(s)

# plot solutions:
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
fg, axx = plt.subplots(2, 1)
axx[0].set_title("Real part of solution of $\\frac{d}{dt}f(t)= (f(t))^4$")
axx[1].set_title("Imag. part of solution of $\\frac{d}{dt}f(t)= (f(t))^4$")
fg.suptitle("$C_1=0.1$")
for i, s in enumerate(sls, start=1):
    fn1 = s.rhs.subs("C1", .1)  # C_1 -> 1
    fn2 = sy.lambdify(t, fn1, modules="numpy")  # make numpy function
    y = fn2(x+0j)  # needs to be called with complex number
    axx[0].plot(x, np.real(y), label="Sol. %d" % i)
    axx[1].plot(x, np.imag(y), label="Sol. %d" % i)
for ax in axx:
    ax.legend(loc="best")
    ax.grid(True)
axx[0].set_ylabel("Re$\\{f(t)\\}$")
axx[1].set_ylabel("Im$\\{f(t)\\}$")
axx[-1].set_xlabel("$t$")
fg.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

In an IPython shell, you should see the following:

[image: Solutions]

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thankyou, very interesting,I have tried your solution with a complex nonlinear equation, but it keeps crunching forever, is there any way to limit the computation time, or do I miss something, the equation: eq1 = sy.Eq(t*(3*f(t).diff(t)-f(t).diff(t)**3), f(t) * (1-3*f(t).diff(t)**2))  And the dsolve:  sls = dsolve(eq1, ics={f(0): -2,  f(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): 0})

Comment: @FabianoTarlao Not sure if a closed form solution exists for your equation - at first sight it does not seem so...